# How convert variable returned from PHP in javascript value?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, parsing

I hope you can help me to find a better title...

I have a php file the return a value:

```
<?php
 $value= "abcd";
 $returned= json_encode($value);
 print_r($returned);
?>
```

I got that value with `ajax`in my **javascript** file.

```
success: function (result) {
    $sku= result;
    console.log($sku);
}
```

Why in `console.log()` is print

```
 "abcd"
```

and not

```
  abcd
```

if in javascript i have `console.log("abcd");` it print only `abcd` without quote.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve and gets hindered by this outcome?

Comment: You're wrapping your string in a JSON encode. Just unencode it on the front end with json.parse, like: `JSON.parse("\"hello\"");`

Comment: @Gavin do you suggest i should not use json_encode in my php file ?

Comment: @Gavin now works ! :D but i didn't understand the reason

Comment: @Borja that entirely depends on what you're trying to do. `print_r` could also cause problems if you're expecting a specific formatted output. If you want JSON on the other side, json encode is fine.

Comment: thank you Borja for stepping up the plate with this great example - just great!

Answer (score 0):

From your question I think, following will resolve the concern.

```
<?php
 $value= "abcd";
 echo json_encode($value);

?>
```

**javascript File**

```
success: function (result) {
    let sku = result;
    console.log(sku);
}
```